# Avoiding duplicates in designing One to Many relationship

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, one-to-many, duplicate-data

I went through many threads and couldn't figure it out. Sorry if this is a duplicate question. Consider the following setup.

1) Employee => (ID,Name)

2) Department => (ID,Name,location,Clerk,Accountant,Middle-manager,Group-manager,Regional-manager,Active)

Department can have many Clerks, Accountants, Middle-managers and so on. They are just employees from the Employee table. Need a better database schema (flexible like, adding up a new column as Divisional-Manager must be easy) for Department entity with NO data duplication, NO update anomalies and NO / less junction tables.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this;

[image: department employee ERD]

```
CREATE TABLE department(
    dept_id      int    NOT NULL,
    dept_name    char(10)    NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK1 PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (dept_id)
)
go


CREATE TABLE department_employee(
    id         int    NOT NULL,
    dept_id    int    NOT NULL,
    emp_id     int    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK3 PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (id)
)
go


CREATE TABLE employee(
    emp_id      int    NOT NULL,
    emp_name    char(10)    NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK2 PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (emp_id)
)
go


ALTER TABLE department_employee ADD CONSTRAINT Refdepartment1 
    FOREIGN KEY (dept_id)
    REFERENCES department(dept_id)
go

ALTER TABLE department_employee ADD CONSTRAINT Refemployee2 
    FOREIGN KEY (emp_id)
    REFERENCES employee(emp_id)
go
```

Comment: NO> I'm not able to see it. :(

Comment: Do we really need ID for department_employee? And also missed the position/title he holds in that department. SO, we can have Position/Title master and include that also in department_employee. 

BTW, thanks for posting the explanation in text considering my inability to view the image.

Comment: No you don't need that ID. You can have dept_id and emp_id as PK of that table. Position/title is an attribute of that department_employee table. You can create a table POSITION (pos_id, pos_name) and have pos_id in department_employee table as a FK.

Answer (score 1):

You have a many-to-many relationship so you need a third association (junction) table - you can't avoid it.

DepartmentMember => (DepartmentId, EmployeeId, MembershipRole)

Why don't you want this?

Comment: This implies that I need to have a MembershipRole table also?

Comment: MembershipRole is just a descriminator value to represent whether it's a clerk, manager, etc... It could be a character, an int, or a varchar, whatever you think is easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Department =>(ID,employeeID,location,active)
Employee =>(EmployeeID,name, position)

I think that would be a much better way of organizing your tables. This assumes that active is a property of the department, else move it to the employee table.

Comment: In this design you can have only one employee in a department.

Comment: not so...
the employeeID changes..., the ID in employee is the employee ID, distinct from department ID

Comment: if you put employeeID in Department table, you can't have more than one employee in a department. That's a fact...

Comment: soandos, create the tables the way you explain and try adding records, you can then understand why.

Comment: I did and it works just fine (in access, but that should not matter). please explain what you think the problem is.

Comment: query that ran, and provided correct data (using the tables above: SELECT Department.ID, Department.EmployeeID, Department.location, Department.active, Employees.name2, Employees.postion
FROM Department INNER JOIN Employees ON Department.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID;
)

Comment: @soandos - You mean to say Department table has composite primary key? (DepartmentID & EmployeeID)

Comment: yes, why not? primary is not strictly needed, worst case. if the number of departments is small, it is easier to do it this way than create another table.

Comment: @soandos, stop, think again and than write. Department table should not/cannot/must not have employee_id even it is composite PK, period! Different data domains. You have to have 3 tables. DEPT (dept_id), EMP(emp_id) and DEPT_EMP (dept_id, emp_id)

Comment: @soandos - I agree with Mevdiven. It terribly duplicates Location & Active columns, right? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Employee =>(ID,name, department_ID, position_ID, Active)
Position =>(ID, name, Active)
Department => (ID,Name,location,Active)
```

Comment: In case you want a certain employee to be able to work in multiple departments, you'll have `Employee =>(ID,name, position_ID, Active)` and `Emp_dep_rel => (employee_ID, department_ID)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an employee can only work in 1 department. IF not, then yes, you need a third table to avoid duplication

Employee

```
ID, Name, EmployeeType, DepartmentID
(pk on ID, EmployeeType)
```

Department

```
ID, Name, Active
```

Comment: It duplicates Active field badly.

Answer (score 0):

> Position/Title is very much contextual
>   to Department. One can be a
>   Regional-Manager in one department and
>   can additionally takes Consultant
>   position in another department.

Then , the department and the Employee is many-to-many. The Employee to the position is also many-to-many. If you need flexibility ,like adding a new title for a department , the junction tables are necessary. You cannot avoid it.

You can refer to the following Table structure for reference:

```
Employee 
-----------------------
EmployeeID (PK)
EmployeeName
Active

Department 
-------------------------
DepartmentID (PK)
DepartmenName
Location

Position 
----------------------------
PositionID (PK)
PositionDescription (eg.Clerk, Accountant etc)

EmployeePosition 
----------------------------
EmployeeID  (FK to Employee.EmployeeID )
DepartmentID (FK to Department.DepartmentID)
PositionID (FK to Position.PositionID )
```

> If the Position/Title is fixed to
>   Employee instead of Department.i.e. An
>   employee who is clerk and can be in
>   that position to one or many dept.,
>   how can we go about it?

Do you mean that  in an extreme case , many employees can have their own special titles ? and they belong to many departments? If yes ,suppose a employee ID 123 has a special title called "The Special One" , and it belongs to the IT , Account and Sales department . You first create this title (i.e "The Special One" ) in the `Position`  table and get the `Position.PositionID`.

Then you insert 3 records for  Employee.EmployeeID 123  into `EmployeePosition`  table using this `Position.PositionID` and the Department ID of IT , Account , Sales departments.

Comment: In my scenario, an employee can have different positions. And position in one department is completely different from the other. So, gotta go with junction tables right?

Comment: @soandos
Position/Title is very much contextual to Department. One can be a Regional-Manager in one department and can additionally takes Consultant position in another department.

Comment: Then  , the department and the Employee  is many-to-many. The Employee   to the position is also many-to-many. If you need flexibility ,like adding a new title for a department , the junction tables  is necessary. You cannot avoid it.

Comment: so this would be it:
tables would be:
Department=>(departmentID,departmentname,active)
Employee=>(employeeID,name)
Employeetodepartment=>(departmentID,employeeID,postion)

Comment: @soandos => yup. May be I can also think about having a master table for Position/Title as well

Comment: @Ken - Thanks a lot for that. I'm curious to know the schema, if the Position/Title is fixed to Employee instead of Department. i.e. An employee who is clerk and can be in that position to one or many dept., how can we go about it?

Comment: @keevas : Welcome , I just updated my answers in respond to your question .